# Not able to access yaml values from the spring boot application

Tags: spring-boot, yaml

I am getting null for hourString and minuteString. Please advice.

Below is my application.yaml file:-

```
inbound:
    out:
        path: inbound/out
    processed:
        path: inbound/processed
    read:
        path: inbound/read
    hour:
        value: 17
    minute:
        value: 00
```

Below is my Java class:-

```
public class Application {

 @Value("${inbound.hour.value}")    
private static String hourString;
 @Value("${inbound.minute.value}")
private static String minuteString;


public static void main(String[] args) {


    Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();
    int hour_of_day =Integer.parseInt(hourString);
    -------
    -------
   }
```

Comment: where is your yml file? in which folder?

Comment: As @pvpkiran already mentioned. Please provide the project structure and don't hide annotations. Is there any annotation on your `Application` class?

Comment: Your variables are static - usually wiring properties with `@Value` only works for non static fields. You also would need to instantiate your class as a bean